# onBackpress not calling when drawarMenu is closed in actionbarActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

I am developing Shopping Application allmost is ready, At main activity extend ActionBarActivity.on This activity leftDrawermenu, tabhost for Fragment. When drawer is open then onBackPress run and performe exitConfirmDialog but if drawer is closed than exitConfirmdialog not show and directly close

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
             OnTabChangeListener,OnTouchListener, OnBackStackChangedListener {



    /** The Sliding list view. */
        private ListView mSlidingListView;

        /** The Main adapter data. */
        private ArrayList<Category> mMainAdapterData;

        /** The Sliding adapter. */
        private SlidingAdapter mSlidingAdapter;

        /** The catalog xml parser. */
        private CatalogXmlParser catalogXmlParser;

        /** The Drawer toggle. */
        private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

        /** The Drawer layout. */
        private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

        /** The Toolbar. */
        private Toolbar mToolbar;

        /** The Ab cart counter. */
        public static TextView mAbCartCounter;

        /** The Ab title. */
        private TextView mAbTitle;

        /** The Ab search. */

        /** The Ab checkout. */
        private View mAbCheckout;

        /** The Ab cart image view. */
        public static View mAbCartImageView;

        /** The Ab login cart image view. (added by nayan)*/
        //private View mAbLoginImageView;
        public View mAbLoginImageView;
        private int ExitFlag=1;

        /** The Ab clear filter. */
        //private View mAbClearFilter;

        /** The Ab search et. */
        private EditText mAbSearchEt;

        /** The Ab cancel search. */
        private View mAbCancelSearch;

        /** The Search text watcher. */
        private SearchTextWatcher mSearchTextWatcher;

        /** The Ab sent. */
        private View mAbSent;

        private Context mContext;

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        private LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager;

        private Bundle savedInstanceState_;

        public List<List<Product>> AdapterData;

        public boolean IsHaveSlider;

        public TabHost tabHost;

        private TextView tabtext;

        private HorizontalScrollView scroll_Focus;
        public static  Set<String> Cart_ProductList = new HashSet<String>();
        public boolean first_Time=true;

        private int tab;

        private View login_lbl;

        private RelativeLayout layout_Cart;

        private Toast toast;

        private ImageView mAbSearch;

        private View mAbClearFilter;    

        public String Current_Fragment_flag;

        public static LinearLayout container;

        public static EditText sampleImage;

        private int AnimationState=0;

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
         */
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            this.mContext = getBaseContext();

            ThemesManager.setCorrectTheme(this, AppSettings.CURRENT_THEME);

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            savedInstanceState_=savedInstanceState;
            MainSplashScreen.isfirsttime=false;

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            mSearchTextWatcher = new SearchTextWatcher();

            ImageLoaderConfiguration imageLoaderConfiguration = ImageOptionsBuilder
                    .createImageLoaderConfiguration(this);
            ImageLoader.getInstance().init(imageLoaderConfiguration);

            catalogXmlParser = CatalogXmlParser.getInstance();

            catalogXmlParser.parseData(this);

            mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            sampleImage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sampleEDT);
            container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_placeholder);


            initActionbar();

          //ADDED BY NAYAN FOR INVISIBLE LOGIN BUTTON FROM ACTIONBAR IF ALREADY LOGGED
            mAbLoginImageView = findViewById(R.id.ab_login_card);
            login_lbl=findViewById(R.id.login_lbl);
            sampleImage.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(AnimationState==0)
                    {
                        mAbCartCounter.animate().rotationYBy(720).setDuration(2000);

                    }

                    mAbCartCounter.animate().setListener(new AnimatorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animator arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            AnimationState=1;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            AnimationState=0;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

            boolean isLogges = ApplicationPreference.getLogInStatus();
            if (isLogges!=true)

            {
                mAbLoginImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                login_lbl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mAbCartImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mAbCartCounter.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
            else
            {
                mAbLoginImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                login_lbl.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                mAbCartImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mAbCartCounter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //END NAYAN
            tabhost();  

            mAbCartImageView.setClickable(true);


            mAbCartCounter.setClickable(true);

            layout_Cart=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_Cart);
            layout_Cart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    int is_cart_visible=mAbCartImageView.getVisibility();
                    if(is_cart_visible==0)
                    {
                        //  showCartFragment(true, false);

                        /*  PopupWindow m_PopUpWindow = new PopupWindow(MainActivity.this);
                          m_PopUpWindow.setContentView(v);
                          m_PopUpWindow.setHeight(50);
                          m_PopUpWindow.setWidth(50);
                          m_PopUpWindow.showAsDropDown(v,300,5);*/

                    //  mAbCartImageView.setClickable(false);
                    //  mAbCartCounter.setClickable(false);
                          boolean isLogges = ApplicationPreference.getLogInStatus();
                            if(isLogges==false)
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(mContext,
                                        mContext.getString(R.string.pls_login),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                            }else
                            {
                                if(Integer.parseInt(mAbCartCounter.getText().toString())>0)
                                {
                                //  mAbCartImageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                    //mAbCartCounter.setError("Please Wait....");
    //                              boolean addToBackStack=false; 
    //                              boolean clearBackStack=false;
    //                              FragmentDirectOrder FragmentDirectOrder1 = new FragmentDirectOrder("").newInstance();
    //                              //fragmentLogin.TAG="Login";
    //                              showScreen(FragmentDirectOrder1, FragmentDirectOrder1.TAG, addToBackStack,clearBackStack);
                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                                    builder.setMessage("please Wait...");
                                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();

                                    // Must call show() prior to fetching text view
                                    TextView messageView = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                                    messageView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

                                    Intent orderBooking = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OrderBookingScreen.class);
                                    orderBooking.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                    orderBooking.putExtra("CALLING", "cart");
                                    startActivity(orderBooking);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please select the product.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);  
                                     LinearLayout linearlayout=(LinearLayout)toast.getView();
                                     TextView msgtext=(TextView)linearlayout.getChildAt(0);
                                     msgtext.setTextSize(12);
                                     toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL,70,3);
                                 //  toast.setMargin(10, 10);
                                     toast.show();
                                }
                                    /*   for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
                         {           
                             TextView tabtext_2=(TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
                             tabtext_2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);            
                             tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                             tabHost.clearFocus();
                         }*/
                    }
                    }else
                    {
                        Intent login_form = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FragmentLogin.class);
                        startActivity(login_form);
                    }
                }
            });
        //  overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);



        }
```

on back press snippet

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        Toast.makeText(this, "DrawerClosed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        Toast.makeText(this, "popBackStack", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "popBackStack", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add some description...

Comment: I am developing Shopping Application allmost is ready, At main activity extend ActionBarActivity.on This activity leftDrawermenu, tabhost for Fragment. When drawer is open then onBackPress run and performe exitConfirmDialog but if drawer is closed than exitConfirmdialog not show and directly close

Comment: public void onBackPressed()
 {
     if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
         mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
         Toast.makeText(this, "DrawerClosed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     } else if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
         getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
         Toast.makeText(this, "popBackStack", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     } else {
      Toast.makeText(this, "popBackStack", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         super.onBackPressed();
     }
 }

Comment: means you want to show exitConfirmDialog on backpress click, right?

Comment: yes Brother pls help me if u have some idea

Comment: And one more thing when focus is on edittext,drawer, then backpress run but focus when on fragment means on place holder when run fragment the backpress Not run.

Comment: remove super.onBackPressed(); and check it.

Comment: Nothing problem is still same

Comment: when you click on backpress then which Toast is going to call???

Comment: if draweris open OR Serach Edittext is RequestFocus than only OnBackPress run means going in event other wise nothing run and application goes in history

Comment: it is too simple, but why it is not working... not getting..

Comment: if you give me your email ID i will send you whole code you understand better

Comment: visit my stackoverflow profile. you will find it.

Comment: create one demo and send it to me. if it is company project. please don't share your code with me.

Comment: Ok i sent you please Check  (pinalkumar.shalom@hotmail.com)

Comment: And if you want to show this app on google Play search "Hitech Board"

Comment: you have no any idea for this problem?

Comment: Ok Finally i have doned Thanks

Comment: great !!! put your answer. if anyone having same issue,  then the answer will help them.

Comment: Just Put this code in my all Fragment

Answer (score 0):

```
mParentView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        mParentView.requestFocus();
        mParentView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){

                    if(ExitFlag == 1)
                    {
                         ExitFlag++;
                        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                        getActivity().onBackPressed();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ExitFlag = 1;
                    }
                }


                return true;
            }
        });
```